# Does google wallet offer an api to send money from person to person and/or mass pay?

Tags: api, paypal, p2p, dwolla, masspay

Our company's system sends hundreds of small payments ($5 to $100 usually) per week to people via the API's offered by paypal and dwolla.  Does google wallet's API offer an equivalent capability?

Comment: Has this situation changed at all in the past four years?

Comment: Our situation has changed.  We're not longer using paypal.  Instead we've gone with an ACH solution provided by our bank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not supported in the API Reference :(

https://developers.google.com/wallet/objects/reference/v1/

Answer (score -3):

Although there is no equivalent API, you may consider the Google Wallet ***Send Money*** feature:

http://www.google.com/wallet/send-money/

More info about features and restrictions here:

http://www.google.com/wallet/faq.html#tab=faq-send